# Changing the sub-element name in XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, saxon, kernow

I'm fairly new to XML and XQuery. 
The XML data that I have looks like:[image]

And what I would like to get as a result is:

```
 <country name="country-name">
      <big>city-name</big>
      <big>city-name</big>
    </country>
```

My Code is:

```
for $a in doc("countries.xml")/countries/country[count(city[population > 7000000])>=1]
return 
<country> {$a/@name}
{let $b := $a/city[population>7000000]/name
return <big>{$b}</big>}
</country>
```

Any hint how can I get the result formatted as above is really appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but as text which we can copy and use to test code we put into answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is you want to omit the `<name>` tags around the city name. You can do so by adding `/data()` when using its value, eg.

```
<big>{$b/data()}</big>
```

Also, you don't need to `count` the elements in a predicate. Predicates are existence quantified; so if there is at least one, it is true, otherwise false. Another problem is you did not loop over the cities. A slightly cleaned up version of your code:

```
for $country in doc("countries.xml")/countries/country[city/population > 7000000]
return 
  <country>{
    $country/@name,
    for $city in $country/city[population > 7000000]
    return <big>{ $city/name/data() }</big>  
  }</country>
```

By using computed element constructors in axis steps (supported by newer XQuery 3.0 implementations, I tested using BaseX), you can condense the code to even fewer lines:

```
for $country in doc("countries.xml")/countries/country[city/population > 7000000]
return element country {
    $country/@name,
    $country/city[population > 7000000]/element big { ./name/data() }
  }
```

Comment: @Janes Erat, Thanks for the help but still doesn't work. It says that System function data#0 is not available with this host language/version.FYI,I'm using Kernow 1.8.

Comment: In this case you can use `text()` instead.

Comment: The use of element{} following "/" is allowed by XQuery 1.0 as well as 3.0, and should work in Saxon too, but I would advise against it because technically, the order of the constructed "big" elements is unpredictable. The "/" sorts them into document order, and document order for a set of parentless element nodes is undefined. You'll probably get away with it, but it's not 100% reliable. The 3.0 "!" operator would be safer.

Comment: In XQuery 1.0, `data()` is not available, you have to write `data(.)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the insights on document order with `/` and `!`! If I got you right, sorting happens _after_ the axis step was performed (thus after constructing the new `<big/>` elements)?